# Div background image scaling on iPad Pro landscape

Tags: html, ipad, background, responsive

Trying to fix the issue with the background image for my title div to make it fully responsive.

Issue is: the size of the background image blows up on iPad Pro in landscape.
It works correctly on desktops, also shows up correctly in Chrome Dev tools for responsive/iPad Pro landscape. The only instance I currently observe this issue is - iPad Pro landscape (both Safari and Chrome). 
See code and screenshots attached.

Website: [rita.im](http://rita.im)
Size of title.jpg file is 2464 × 1632

CSS for the Div

```
`.bgimage {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../img/title.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`
```

[Chrome Dev tools preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPz1a.jpg)

[Actual iPad Pro landscape display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPJ4o.jpg)

Thank you! Will post answer if I resolve the issue myself first.

Comment: Check if anything is outside the viewport. Swipe left on iPad to see if you can. If all is in viewport you shouldn’t be able to. Just a thought, not a true answer.

Comment: Thank you for response. No, nothing outside, everything is fit to width.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

, which was there for "parallax" effect seems to have been the problem. Without it, background images display at correct scale. Will have to find a way to add parallax for banner on iOS with JavaScript.